# User events in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, events, usermodel

How do I capture user events in Craft 3? I looked at the documentation but couldn't figure it out. I need to capture after user registration events and after user save events.

Here is what I tried, I know it's not correct but I think I'm pretty close

```
Event::on(
    Users::class,
    Users::EVENT_AFTER_USER_SAVE,
    function (PluginEvent $event) {
        // do something
    }
);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There aren't specific User element save events in Craft 3, but you can listen to `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT` and check if the element is a user like so:

```
Event::on(\craft\services\Elements::class, \craft\services\Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) {
    if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\User) {
        // Do your thing.
    }
});
```

For user activation, there's `EVENT_AFTER_VERIFY_EMAIL`:

```
Event::on(\craft\services\Users::class, \craft\services\Users::EVENT_AFTER_VERIFY_EMAIL, function(UserEvent $event) {
    $user = $event->user
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, it gave me an error for function(UserEvent $event), I changed it to function(Event $event)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try `User::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE`. I'm not sure that it's documented anywhere, or if it was added after Brad responded, but it might work too.

```
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\elements\User
use craft\events\ModelEvent;

Event::on(
    User::class,
    User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent $event) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!!